# How to get started on creating a safe that will open and close upon entering a passcode into it?

Tags: c, node.js, arduino, hardware, interactive

I want to work on a project dealing with some hardware things but I have no knowledge in this area and I would really appreciate some help with getting started.

I am programming in Node.js so I have had a look at NodeBots and Arduino; however, I am not sure if this is the right place to even start.

The main thing I want to be able to do is:

- create a safe where it will open when I enter the correct passcode into an iPad or some touch screen
- be able to set the passcode

When working on such a project, do I need the hardware first? (If so, what are some things I should get?)
Secondly, where can I start coding and what are good languages for this? (I am unsure as to which aspect of this project I should focus on first)

Comment: You should probably start by playing around with simple hardware prototypes and try and make them do simple things.  Just "hello world" type programs just to get familiar with how to do simple stuff.  Then break the project down into smaller testable pieces.  Implement the pieces and the tests.  Repeat until complete.

Comment: When you are done, don't forget to clear the buffer where the passcode was entered. My colleague made one, and was crest-fallen when I opened the safe just by pressing "Enter".

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I am sure that'll be really helpful :) @WeatherVane

Answer (score 0):

I made one with a keypad (not connected to other devices, but it's similar). And, according to my experience, the mechanical part is the worst: designing and building the safe (I used plexiglass) was the worst thing.

As for your questions, I think that yes, you should start with the hardware design. Or at least choose

1. how are ou closing/opening the door? I used a stepper motor, but there are tons of choices - door locks, servomotors, dc motors.....
2. how are you detecting if it is open or closed?
3. what will be the interface? You spoke about iPad, so I suppose you want some bluetooth apple-enabled devices.

Then you will be able to start coding. But the code will be really simple once you got what the hardware will look like (in the end, it's just "wait for the correct passcode, then open the safe, then close it again").

Comment: I see! Thank you, these are some great questions to get me started :) @frarugi87

Comment: @Sarah, frarugi87 makes the software sound easy, but there is a big difference between "code that works" and "robust industrial code". For one example, suppose the owner types in 3 of the 4 digits but the phone rings, and then forgets about the safe? That would need a timeout to reset the passcode entry, otherwise it would leave the safe very unsafe, having a 1 in 10 chance of a single digit opening it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yup, I see what you mean, there are quite a lot of cases that I would need to consider. Would you say that a good place to begin would be to do some work with Arduino and a keypad in Java? Thanks!

Comment: @Sarah I only have enough experience of java to know it suits high-level applications whereas C is good for low level engineering. If you plan to use Arduino (I haven't) I can only recommend following the path of least resistance, that is to begin with the simplest and most accessible tools on offer.